# Close Windows Phone App when lock screen button Press

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Source Code in C# When Lock screen button pressed windows phone app will close. and also close when start button  press?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Also try to posing this question such that people can understand you (I can't, for instance). Add some description of what you're doing.

Comment: if i press the lock screen button i want to close the app or app restart. app start on the splah screen. One more thing then i click the start button i want to close the app not running on the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this purpose

in App.xaml.cs,

```
 private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
        {
                         Application.Current.Terminate();

        }
```

Comment: i also using the EmailComposeTask on my app when i click in the EmailComposeTask button the app also close. i dont want this, give me some that code then i click the lock screen, start button my app close on back ground , and when i click the EmailComposeTask its not close.

Comment: You can use global bool for that

Comment: @kami then approve pls so one can take help form this